# Exporting huge matrices from Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, matrix

I have a few values generated in Matlab by

```
for count =  1:30

-Do stuff-

Data{Count} = [Multiple values] %here

end %Count
```

I'm trying to copy this large chunk of data to MS Excel, but I always get this:

[image: From a Matlab variable]

...and then I have to open every matrix in each cell one by one to extract their values. I would love to see all the matrices when I open the variable in Matlab, something like this:

[image]

and easily copy and paste them into excel, which is why I segregated them into 1, 2, 3... in the first place.

Any opinions? Matlab Ver 2010b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are storing your data in a cell array, and I assume your Data{c} are column vectors, for example:

```
    data    = cell(1,2);
    data{1} = [1; 2; 3; 4];
    data{2} = [5; 6; 7; 8];
```

From here, you can construct a table via

```
    T = table(data{1},data{2},'VariableNames',{'sample1','sample2'});
```

or, for larger data sets,

```
    T = array2table(cell2mat(data));
```

This assumes an equal number of entries in each of your cells, else you will run into a concatenation error using cell2mat. One workaround here would be to pad your data{c} with zeros to get consistent dimensions, although this could mess up you data analysis.

In the case of varying numbers of entries in each data{c}, I would suggest instead that you store each data value
in a separate cell, i.e.

```
    for c = 1:n
    ...
    values = [some values];        
        for r = 1:length(values)        
            data{r,c} = values(r);    
        end
    end
```

and use the cell2table() function:

```
    T = cell2table(data);
```

You can then export to Excel via

```
    filename = 'test.xlsx';
    writetable(T,filename)
```

Comment: the OP has a for-loop to generate data dynamically. Your answer has absolute bounds. Does it even work when the arrays in the cells have different sizes?

Comment: Thanks for this, edited to deal with different array sizes in cells.

Comment: Thanks... But please don't use i and j as variables, since they can represent the imaginary unit.

Comment: Fair. But more helpful would be if you shared what counter names are typically used. In my code I use "ii", "jj", etc, (or something relevant to the actual application), but this looked messy in the context of the answer

Comment: There are no typically used ones. It depends on the programmer. I would probably use `m` and `k` (since `n` is already used) or `r` and `c` (rows / columns) in this code. Of course `ii` and `jj` is totally ok as well.

Comment: Thanks, edited. Actually "r" and "c" are very nice here.

Comment: You guys are awesome. Unfortunately Matlab R2010b doesn't have cell2table and the related functions, so I had to use a combination of dlmwrite & xlswrite. http://w3facility.org/question/print-a-cell-array-as-txt-in-matlab/  I still used your suggested code to store the data in cells though.